# Getting an IEnumerable of all values in a certain column

Tags: c#, automated-tests, kendo-grid, ui-automation, atata

I'm currently working with the Atata framework and using a Kendo grid. What I'm trying to achieve is getting an IEnumerable or a collection containing all the values in a column. The kendo grid is defined as below:

```
public KendoGrid<TransactionGroupsRow, _> TransactionGroupsGrid { get; private set; }

public class TransactionGroupsRow : KendoGridRow<_>
    {
        [FindByColumnHeader("Group Name")]
        public Link<_> GroupName { get; private set; }
    }
```

I not only want a collection of all the links GroupName, I specifically want the text component of them i.e. what the link would read like on the screen.

[image: An example of the links and their text]

So in this example I would want an IEnumerable containing "002999" and "003999".

Let me know if I need to provide additional detail. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the datasource look like that feeds the Kendo grid with data?  Can you not query/select the datasource itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do that.

1. Use `SelectData` method. It works quite fast for list of items with count <= 50.

   ```
   // Just get all items:
   IEnumerable<string> groupNames = page.TransactionGroupsGrid.Rows
       .SelectData(x => x.GroupName.Content.Value).Value;

   // Assert items:
   page.TransactionGroupsGrid.Rows
       .SelectData(x => x.GroupName.Content.Value).Should.Contain("002999", "003999");
   ```
2. The faster way is using `SelectContentsByExtraXPath` method. This one will work very fast even for a table with 1000 rows. But you need to specify a relative XPath to the table cell `td` element inside a row `tr` element. This can also be extracted to the page object class as a method.

   ```
   // Just get all items:
   IEnumerable<string> groupNames = page.TransactionGroupsGrid.Rows
       .SelectContentsByExtraXPath("td[1]", "Group Names").Value;

   // Assert items:
   page.TransactionGroupsGrid.Rows
       .SelectContentsByExtraXPath("td[1]", "Group Names").Should.Contain("002999", "003999");
   ```

You can also check [Performance Practices for ControlList](https://github.com/atata-framework/atata-samples/tree/master/Performance.ControlList) Atata sample project.